# Can I add right-click options in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, right-click

In Google Chrome, if I select a piece of text and right click on it, I get the option to:

'Search Google for [text]'

I find this extremely useful but I'd also like to be able to add my own options.

For example, I'd like to add the ability to search amazon.co.uk using the selected text or go straight to Google maps using the selected text (i.e. an address or postcode) and so on.

I can sort of add this functionality using [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/) but would rather be able to do it straight from Chrome - is it possible?

Comment: I'm looking for something like 'Context Menu Search' with shortcut keys. Is there any extension doing that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's an extension that uses the Context Menus API to add options to the right click menu for selected text and lets you define your own custom searches.

- [Context Menu Search](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ocpcmghnefmdhljkoiapafejjohldoga)

Try `http://maps.google.com/maps?q=TESTSEARCH` for Google Maps and `http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=TESTSEARCH` for Amazon.co.uk.

Comment: Yes, I think this does exactly what I want - thanks. By the way, need to add the term TESTSEARCH in your strings to use the selected word or phrase and it works great.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I'm looking for something like 'Context Menu Search' with shortcut keys. Is there any extension doing that?

Answer (score 21):

There's a Context Menus API available in the developer and beta channels as of recently. You can use it to write your own extensions which add options to the right click menu. Note that this will only work for Google Chrome version 6 and higher.

Here's an example from the official extensions gallery:

- [Imgur Uploader](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hgmpmjpekinnebjgnakcahjikbomnmlb) (upload an image to Imgur on right click)

I also wrote three of my own, based on that code:

- [TinEye Right Click](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1532709/TinEye_Right_Click.crx) (perform a reverse image search at TinEye on right click)
- [Wikipedia Right Click](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1532709/Wikipedia_Right_Click.crx) (search for articles about selected text at Wikipedia on right click)
- [Merriam-Webster Right Click](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1532709/Merriam-Webster_Right_Click.crx) (look up definition of selected text at Merriam-Webster on right click)

You can install those at your own risk by right clicking the links, clicking *Save Link As…*, finding the files on your computer, and dragging them into a Google Chrome window.

Read about the API here:

- [Context Menus](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/)

To write your own, you need a manifest.json file, which should look something like this:

```
{
   "background_page": "background.html",
   "description": "Add a context menu item to search for selected text at Google Maps.",
   "icons": {
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "48": "icon48.png"
   },
   "minimum_chrome_version": "6",
   "name": "Google Maps Right Click",
   "permissions": [ "contextMenus", "tabs" ],
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

You also need a background.html file, which should look something like this:

```
<script>

function searchgooglemaps(info)
{
 var searchstring = info.selectionText;
 chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + searchstring})
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({title: "Search Google Maps", contexts:["selection"], onclick: searchgooglemaps});

</script>
```

Lastly, you should have at least a 16 × 16 pixel icon for the context menu and a 48 × 48 pixel icon for the extensions management page. You can also specify a 128 × 128 pixel icon, which is shown during installation, and a 32 × 32 pixel icon if you want to submit your extension to the official gallery. All of your icons need to be listed in manifest.json. Make sure file types and names match up.

Put the icons, background.html, and manifest.json in a folder together, then go to the extensions management page at `chrome://extensions`, look under *Developer mode* (I think you need to be running the beta channel or higher for this to show up), click on *Pack extension…*, next to *Extension root directory* click *Browse…*, locate and select the folder you made, click *OK*, and drag the resulting .crx file into your Google Chrome window.

Comment: Thanks for this Charlatan. I had heard about the new API but was waiting until I found the extension that fulfillled my wishes before posting it here as the final answer. I very much doubt I'll try making my own as there are far better people to do that than me. Perhaps the Author of the 'Context Search' extension will rewrite it to make use of the new API.

Comment: You're welcome. It's really very easy to adapt the above examples for other sites. All you have to do to get it working is change the URL. Everything else is just making it pretty. I've edited the code in my answer to work for searching Google Maps. Only had to change five things.

Comment: Note that there are some changes to chrome extensions, namely that the `manifest.json` is now version 2 and a lot of this stuff has changed.

Comment: Your links to Dropbox are broken. Willing to update?

Comment: @BobHopez Those extensions no longer work with all the changes to Chrome in the last nine years.

Comment: I was so happy to find this. Unfortunately, all dead links as of 2020... Definitely what I want to do though.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [Context Search](http://www.chromeextensions.org/other/context-search/) extension which does what you want with an exception that it does not add anything to the right click menu; instead, after you select a chunk of text on page, it will show a small button with blue triangle next to it, and clicking on it will pop up menu.
[image]

Comment: Excellent. This does 99% of what I want. As you say, it doesn't add the options to the right click menu but, more importantly, it doesn't work everywhere e.g. write something in the Google search box, select it and the button doesn't appear. I'd still like to hear if it's possible to add the options to the right click menu but this will do to be getting on with. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK there are no way to add options to Chrome native menus (like the "Options" menu in top-right) because extensions can only tweak DOM and display pop-ups. Probably that was an intentional choice to achieve better cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: This is one reason I'm sticking to Firefox.

Comment: @CGA: Firefox is nice, and I used it for years, but it is waay too sloow on Atom 2x1600 netbook.

Comment: Can't disagree with you there.

Answer (score 3):

I've been enjoying an extension called [Custom Right-Click Menu](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-right-click-menu/onnbmgmepodkilcbdodhfepllfmafmlj?hl=en-US)
It allows you to create fully configurable right-click menu items, and even works in other browsers (Opera: [Install Chrome Extensions](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/install-chrome-extensions/), Firefox: [Chrome Store Foxified](https://github.com/Noitidart/Chrome-Store-Foxified)).

- Install "Custom Right-Click Menu" from the Chrome Store
- Open the Options for Custom Right-Click Menu
- In the Editing the CRM section, select Selection
- Scroll down to Commonly Used Search Engines, and add one
- It adds that search engine in the Editing the CRM section.
- Click on it, not on its gear, to edit it.
- Change the name to "Search amazon.co.uk" or whatever
- Change the code to

  ```
   var query;
   var url = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=%s";
   if (crmAPI.getSelection()) {
       query = crmAPI.getSelection();
   } else {
       query = window.prompt('Please enter a search query.');
   }
   if (query) {
       window.open(url.replace(/%s/g,query), '_blank');
   }
  ```
- Create another menu item of the script type, call it "Google Map" or whatever, and code it the same way:

  ```
   var query;
   var url = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/%s";
   if (crmAPI.getSelection()) {
       query = crmAPI.getSelection();
   } else {
       query = window.prompt('Please enter a search query.');
   }
   if (query) {
       window.open(url.replace(/%s/g,query), '_blank');
   }
  ```

Comment: **+1!** You can check it on [**github**](https://github.com/SanderRonde/CustomRightClickMenu), customizing the _root node name_ will **not conflict** on `key_press` with _Copy_, there is **_Import/Export_ feature** and great **support** with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension called "Context Menu Search". It lets you add URLs to it, and then when you select a text, and click one of the URLs, it passes that text to the URL you clicked.

For example, the search URL for YouTube is:

> http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=TESTSEARCH

where TESTSEARCH is the text you want to search for. In the extension, you add this line and it'll automatically replace TESTSEARCH with the selected text when you press it. You can ofcourse add a label for each URL.

Here is the link to the extension.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ocpcmghnefmdhljkoiapafejjohldoga

Answer (score 0):

Hi since the main question has been answered I want to contribute with something.

This is a simply modified script similar to reverse image search with google but redirects imglink.jpg to Jeffrey's Exif Viewer to analyze the EXIF of an image.

Thanks to [gdejohn](https://superuser.com/a/188196/364367).

Easy, create this 2 files I used notepad, add some icons 16x16, 48x48 and 128x128 (or delete line) and go to chrome://extensions/ tick developer mode add the containing folder of the files.

Filename: manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
    "background" : { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
    "description": "Agrega un menu contextual para ver el EXIF de imagenes. Jeffrey's Exif Viewer",
    "icons": {
            "16": "icon16.png",
            "48": "icon48.png",
            "128": "icon128.png"
        },
   "minimum_chrome_version": "6",
   "name": "Regex Exif Viewer Right Click",
   "permissions": [ "contextMenus", "tabs", "http://*/*",
 "https://*/*" ],
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

Filename: background.js

```
/**
 * Returns a handler which will open a new tab when activated.
 */


function getClickHandler() {
  return function(info, tab) {

    // The srcUrl property is only available for image elements.

var url = "http://regex.info/exif.cgi?imgurl=" + info.srcUrl;

    // Create a new tabto the info page.

chrome.tabs.create({ url: url, });
  };
};



/**
 * Create a context menu which will only show up for images.
 */


chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "Get image info via Jeffrey's Exif Viewer",
  "type" : "normal",
  "contexts" : ["image"],
  "onclick" : getClickHandler()
});
```