# How to Add Context Menu Options in the Latest Version of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, context-menu

The answer to this question was discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/179347) but no longer applies to the latest Chrome.

I need to add a custom parent item to the context menu; specifically, a search tool that will apply selected/highlighted text to 1 string of other text. Rather than use another extension, I want to learn how to create a custom option. I could not apply the previous answer to the new documentation.

Comment: could you state what your version of Chrome is for posterity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've developed an extension which adds context menu entries. You can fork my extension [TweetRight](https://github.com/arpitnext/tweetright) for your use.

I guess that @gdejohn's code stopped working because Chrome has implemented Content-Security-Policy for extensions, which does not allow inline JavaScript code, unless asked for. Hence, the code in `background.html` would not execute.

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I was looking for. I will see if I can modify it for my purposes.