# How to add "delete" option in right click menu in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Google has removed the "delete" option in right click menu in chrome. Although many people complain this, google did't hear that.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/NGtuIc87GD4;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/category$3AStable%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/j-gTPZC0W6o

Without "delete", it is very inconvenient. I want to add it back by myself. I tried to find methods to add "delete" options in the right click menu, but I can't find any. Can somebody teach me how to add "delete" option in right click menu in chrome? Thank you very much!!

Comment: What's wrong with ctrl+x?

Comment: What is wrong with using delete on keyboard? I mean, is there a specific need for this context menu or just preference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I add right-click options in Google Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/179347/can-i-add-right-click-options-in-google-chrome)