# in Google Chrome, can I add a right-click command for the current link?

Tags: google-chrome

In particular, I want the command to open a given address passing the clicked link's address as a parameter e.g. if I click on www.home.com, I want the right-click menu to offer a command to open https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=www.home.com .

Note: this is not a duplicate of [Can I add right-click options in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/179347/can-i-add-right-click-options-in-google-chrome) .

Comment: I think that I did not exactly understand the question (I'm not native English speaker) Do you want to handle right click then redirect/open in new tab some url?